# Get the user's consent or approval programmatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I've been able to get the Calendar API up and running with a spring boot project using a Service Account with Domain Wide Delegation Authority.

When I send an email invitation for a Google Meet, the message always goes to the Spam folder first time and then when they mark it as **not spam** or indicate that they **know the sender** in their Calendar dashboard. It goes to the inbox subsequently for subsequent meet invitations.

So imagine If I've an app that allows user to book online video sessions using their Gmail Address.

Does it means they always have to indicate they known my organization as a Sender **first time** for any video session?

Is there a way I can get the user's consent or approval programmatically that they know my organization so that first time when I send them an invitation, it will automatically land in their inbox?

Else the only thing I can think of is to show them a guide on how to recognize that it is actually my organization sending them this email first time.

The idea of the user allowing invitations from everyone in their dashboard doesn't seem feasible or viable to me. The protection policy by Google is good.

I'm aware of the policy Google implemented to prevent spam

https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/07/invitations-from-known-senders-only-google-calendar.html

https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/13009942892311-Google-Calendar-Invitations-Unknown-Sender-emails-

https://help.doodle.com/hc/en-us/articles/11487756131986-Google-Calendar-Invitations-Unknown-Sender-